# Is it possible to work full time in an industry position while on sabbatical?

Tags: ethics, university, professorship, funding, sabbatical

The standard situation in US research universities is for the university to pay one semester of salary for a year of sabbatical leave, and faculty typically take this sabbatical at another university or research lab, where there is a clear sense of how to fund the sabbatical.

I'm interested to know whether anyone has experience on how to (ethically) fund an industry sabbatical.  Specifically:

- Is it possible to work full time in an industry position?  If so, do you get half-pay?  Half-hours?
- What (ethical) obligations do you have to ongoing grants (say from the National Science Foundation) during such a sabbatical year?
- What (ethical) obligations do you have towards the university that is paying a semester of salary?

Answer (score 4):

Every university has a policy for addressing these matters, and it is best that you obtain the specific policy from your own institution -- a general survey of what goes on at other places will likely not be informative to your present situation.  Federal funding sometimes can be used to cover the other part of your salary -- but, again, it depends on the funding source and the rules of your institution.

Comment: (-1) Of course every university has its own policies ... but there is a generally accepted standard, and a forteriori so for NSF grants.

Comment: @AriTrachtenberg  So, if I give you answers that relate specifically to my own university, how will you use that information?  Wouldn't it be easier just having this conversation with your own university so you are clear that you are in compliance with policy?

Comment: @AriTrachtenberg, if there are generally accepted standards, please provide them as an answer.

Comment: @BillBarth Do you have evidence that the standards vary significantly from university to university?

Comment: @AriTrachtenberg, no, but you have asserted that there *are* standards, so I was hoping that you could provide them as an answer. I don't think everyone here even knows what these standards are.

Comment: I would have expected Brian P's answer to be as correct as possible under the given information. If the OP believes it is not, he should provide factual information corroborating why he makes this judgement, otherwise the comment (and downvote!) is not helpful. What does the NSF see as standard and what does the OP's university see as standard and what question does this still leave open?